# Why isn't this link to tag linking to the correct model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models

So after pulling my hair out for an hour, I decided to post this here. I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Articles#show

Showing /home/leon/sites/VIS/app/views/articles/_article.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `user_path' for #<#<Class:0x7fdd81fe1eb8>:0x7fdd81fdfdc0>
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <div id="left-column">
2:  <p class="label-b">Author<br>
3:     <%= link_to "#{@article.user.penname}'s profile", user_path(article.user) %>
```

user_path(article.user) %>

When I try to link to the article's authoring user. My routes file:

```
  resources :tags

  get "admin/index"
  get "admin/show"
  get "articles/contact"
  get "articles/about"

  resources :roles

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" }

  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
```

I do have a belongs_to :user in my article model file and a has_many :articles in my user model file. I'm using this link to link to the author's profile within the article.

Please help! I'm using can can for my permission management and devise for my authentication, but its throwing the error within the show action of the article so I didn't post that code. Let me know if I should. Thanks!

@Jacob

I get the same error:

NoMethodError in Articles#show

Showing /home/leon/sites/VIS/app/views/articles/_article.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `user_path' for #<#:0x7fdd82217a98>
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: 
2:  Author
3:     <%= link_to "#{@article.user.penname}'s profile", article.user %>
4:     Previous Versions
5:     Version 7

6:     <%= image_tag "add-to-favorites.png", :class => "favorites-button" %>

The relevant part of my routes:

```
{:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"roles"}
      new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
          user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
  destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)                         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
         user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                         {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
     new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                     {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
    edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
         user_password PUT    /users/password(.:format)                         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
     user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users/registrations"}
 new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users/registrations"}
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                             {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users/registrations"}
     user_registration PUT    /users(.:format)                                  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users/registrations"}
     user_registration DELETE /users(.:format)                                  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users/registrations"}
     user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)                     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
 new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format)                 {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
     user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)                     {:action=>"show", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
```

Aha! It doesn't have a route for user#show, but i'm not sure why as I have:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
...
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @user }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
      format.html
    end

  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    respond_to_not_found(:json, :xml, :html)
  end
```

in my app/controllers folder. Do I need to move my users controller into app/controllers/devise and overload it with devise instead of application controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. After playing around with the routes for a while and reading the rails documentation, I added this line to my routes file:

devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" }

resources :users, :only => [:index, :show] <== THIS LINE

below my devise_for routes. This allows me to display the user profiles without having to worry about the edit update etc. roles that devise provides for. Thanks for the answers anyway guys, I appreciate it!

Comment: Out of curiosity were you supposed to be using `@article.user`? You used two different variables in the same `link_to`.

Comment: Yeah, I am kinda new to rails and wasn't sure if it was or not when I originally posted it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
 <%= link_to "#{@article.user.penname}'s profile", article.user %>
```

And Rails will automatically determine the route.

As seen here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

**Update**

Yes, you are going to have to inherit from the DeviseController rather than the ApplicationController. From here you can add your own custom actions, such as show(which is what you doing now).

Look at: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

and search for: Configuring controllers

Answer (score 0):

Try `article.user` instead of `user_path(article.user)`. If that doesn't work, can you post the output from `rake routes`?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it just be: `@article.user` instead of `article.user` ??

```
<%= link_to "#{@article.user.penname}'s profile", @article.user %>
```

Why would you use an instance variable for the user penname and a local variable for the user object? I think that's your problem.

Comment: No, the main problem was that when i did rake routes, the user#show action wasn't being routed at all, and that's where the error was. I also changed article back to @article, but that was just one of the many things i tried to make it work before I figured it out.